# No wireless internet after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: wireless, upgrade, internet, 13.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 my wireless internet at home stopped working.  The UI says that I am connected but when I try to open firefox no pages load.  The internet does work if I plug in my laptop directly to the modem or if I use my computer in windows (dual boot).  It is then clearly an issue with Ubuntu since the wireless internet works in a different operating system.  The wireless internet also works in Ubuntu when I am in Ubuntu and logged into a different wireless network at university but not on my wireless network at home.  Thank you to anyone who can (and takes the time to) help,

Fred

Comment: If you put in the IP address for your router, does it show you the web interface? (Can you access local pages?)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Find what type of wireless card you have in your system, open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), run `lspci` and look up something like this:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation **BCM4311** 802.11b/g **WLAN** (rev 01)
```

based in your results of your chip name (my case **b43**) run:

```
sudo apt get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge the name of your chip (mine is [**bcmw-kernel-source**])
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-source
sudo modprobe chip name
```